# HTTP error code when server cannot find a user-given external resource

Tags: rest, http

Our image board allows users to upload images by copy-pasting URLs. A client app sends a POST request to our API with an image URL given in the request body. Our web service receives the POST request and handles it by downloading the image from the given URL by using a server-side HTTP client ([request](https://github.com/request/request) in our case).

In successful case, the service finds the image, downloads it, and stores it to the server. The service returns HTTP 200 to the client.

Now, what if the image cannot be found? What if the download attempt results in HTTP 404? What HTTP error code should we use to response to the client?

[HTTP 400 Bad Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) is not applicable because the request was well-formed and all parameters were valid.

[HTTP 404 Not Found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) is not applicable because the request URL was found and served although the image URL was not.

[HTTP 502 Bad Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) does not feel right either because there is nothing wrong with our server or the upstream server (the server of the source image). The user just happened to type in an image URL that does not exist.

Any experience on the matter? Which error code is the most correct?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should decide if this is a client error (4xx) or server error (5xx).  From what you describe, it feels more like a client error.  The client has requested the creation of a resource from another resource (the image URL) which does not exist.

There is no perfect match for this scenario, although one could make a case for each of the 2 following response codes:

**HTTP 409 Conflict**:  From the [RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.10):

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current
> state of the target resource. This code is used in situations where
> the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the
> request...

This applies to your case if you consider the target resource to be in a bad state (image not found).  If someone provides an image at the specified URL, that effectively transitions your resource to a valid state.

This is also a good match because, as the RFC states, this code implies the user might be able to resolve the conflict (in your case the user would correct this by posting the image to the specified URL).

**HTTP 424 Failed Dependency**: From the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.4):

> The 424 (Failed Dependency) status code means that the method could
> not be performed on the resource because the requested action depended
> on another action and that action failed...

This applies to your case in that "*the requested action depended on another action and that action failed*".  The dependent action is the posting of an image to the other URL.  What you have described is a case where that dependent action either failed or did not happen (which could also be called a failure).

Answer (score 0):

Since the API determines on something that is not available, its service is unavailable as well.

The status code 503: Service Unavailable is the best fit for your situation. 
According to the [RFC description](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD handle the response as it would for a 500 response.

**Alternatively**, if your API supports a way of communicating errors (e.g. to tell the user that the information he submitted is incorrect) you may be able to use this method to tell the user that the external resource is unavailable. This might be a little friendlier and might avoid some error raises on the user's side.

Since the client app sends POST requests to your API server the response codes should be generated according to the received server in your case this is your API server.

If the server has received correct information from the client app and server determines the request as valid, it should return apropriate code with proper `JSON` or header based error messages.

Comment: 503 does not seem appropriate. This is not a case of the server failing to handle the request because of overload or maintenance.  The server *does* handle the request, it just does not result in the creation of a new resource.  Also, the RFC states that this is a temporary condition that "will be alleviated after some delay".  This is not a good match for what the OP has described.

Answer (score 0):

http error codes were conceived assuming that all pages possibly served were stored locally, one way or another.

Your scenario does not match that assumption and it should therefore not come as a surprise that you don't find codes that fit your bill properly.

Your "not found" scenario is in fact an application error and you should notify your user of the situation by providing an error message on the form where he entered the URL (or return a fully dedicated error page or some such).  Or choose an http error nonetheless and accept the notion that it will be a poor fit no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, what if the image cannot be found? What if the download attempt results in HTTP 404? What HTTP error code should we use to response to the client?

The main thing to keep in mind: you are trying to fool the client into thinking that you are a web site - just a dumb document store which might respond to some content editing messages.

For the client, the primary means of communication is the *body* of the response.  See [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5)

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

The status code is meta-data: aimed at giving the *generic* components participating in the exchange a chance to know what is going on (examples: the web browser doesn't need to know what page you are asking for to recognize a [redirection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4) response returned by the server, the web browser asking for credentials when it receives a [401 unauthorized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) response, web caches [invalidating](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) entries, or not, depending on the status code returned by the response).

> HTTP 400 Bad Request is not applicable because the request was well-formed and all parameters were valid.

Yes, that's exactly right.

I would probably use [500 Internal Server Error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1), on the grounds that there's nothing wrong with the _document that the server received, the problems are all involved in the *side effects* of the server's implementation.

A different approach you might consider: [202 Accepted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3).  Roughly translated "I got your message, I understood your message, and I'll get around to it later."  If you don't need the side effects to be synchronous, you can defer judgment.  That allows you to do things like applying a retry strategy.

> The representation sent with this response ought to describe the request's current status and point to (or embed) a status monitor that can provide the user with an estimate of when the request will be fulfilled.

"I'll get to it later; if you want to know how it is going, go ask him -->"

Because 202 is a non-error status code, its effect on caches is different from those of a 4xx or 5xx.  If you are already thinking ahead about caching, you'll want to the implications of that in mind.